# python struct.pack(): pack multiple datas in a list or a tuple

Tags: python, list, struct

Say i have a `list` or a `tuple` containing numbers of type `long long`,

```
x = [12974658, 638364, 53637, 63738363]
```

If want to `struct.pack` them individually, i have to use

```
struct.pack('<Q', 12974658)
```

or if i want to do it as multiple, then i have to explicitly mention it like this

```
struct.pack('<4Q', 12974658, 638364, 53637, 63738363)
```

But, how can i insert items in a `list` or `tuple` inside a `struct.pack` statement.  I tried using `for` loop like this.

```
struct.pack('<4Q', ','.join(i for i in x))
```

got error saying `expected string, int found`, so i converted the list containing type `int` into `str`, now it gets much more complicated to pack them. Because the whole list gets converted into a string( like a single sentence).

As of now im doing some thing like

```
binary_data = ''
x = [12974658, 638364, 53637, 63738363]
for i in x:
    binary_data += struct.pack('<Q', i)
```

And i unpack them like

```
struct.unpack('<4Q', binary_data)
```

**My question:** is there a better way around, like can i directly point a `list` or `tuple` inside the `struct.pack` statement, or probably a one liner ?

Comment: i also tried [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368263/python-struct-pack-for-individual-elements-in-a-list). didn't help. i get error as `bad char in struct format`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can [splat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator), I'm sorry "unpack the argument list":

```
>>> struct.pack("<4Q", *[1,2,3,4])
'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

If the length of the list is dynamic, you can of course build the format string at runtime too:

```
>>> x = [1, 2] # This could be any list of integers, of course.
>>> struct.pack("<%uQ" % len(x), *x)
'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: haa... i was trying it like `struct.pack('<Q'*4, *x)` as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368263/python-struct-pack-for-individual-elements-in-a-list)... Now i get it,.. Thanks for the help `unwind`. 
+1 for 'if list is dynamic'