# How do you pack three bytes into a python struct?

Tags: python, arrays, pack

Given a hex value of **0x183C6** I'd like to write out its corresponding byte value using exactly 3 bytes. I know that struct would do this to 4 bytes but my constraints are to 3 bytes.

So

```
>>> val = 0x183c6
>>> struct.pack('>L', val)
'\x00\x01\x83\xc6'
```

Is great but I just want:

```
'\x01\x83\xc6'
```

I could post process and strip it after the fact, I could break it up and put each individual byte into a bytearray(), or perhaps do some bit shifting but I wonder if there is a easier way of doing it within struct without post processing.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794640/python-struct-pack-pack-multiple-datas-in-a-list-or-a-tuple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the value into its high byte and low 16-bit word with `divmod`:

```
>>> struct.pack(">BH", *divmod(0x183c6, 1<<16))
'\x01\x83\xc6'
```

To unpack,

```
>>> struct.unpack(">I", '\x00' + '\x01\x83\xc6')
```

Comment: But how would you unpack it?

Comment: I have a byte array, so I'm doing: `struct.unpack(">I", b'\0' + data)`, for me `'\x00'` won't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that, since that's not how structs work. If you absolutely know that the value will never exceed 3 bytes, you can use big-endian encoding for both packing and unpacking:

```
>>> val = 0x183c6
>>> packed = struct.pack('>L', val)[1:]
>>> packed
'\x01\x83\xc6'
>>> '{0:x}'.format(struct.unpack('>L', '\x00' + packed)[0])
'183c6'
```

Note that the packed value will pretty much be useless for passing to other C functions, or similar.